# Salesforce Mobile SDK - refresh token validity period

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android, refresh-token

Is there any document or reference about the validity period of `refreshtoken` of Mobile SDK? I have a hybrid local app and if I let the app to be idle for a while and use back, it's failing with the log `Undefind character, error is not defined in line 336 at Cordova.force.js` This line is the `error` argument of the `forcetkRefresh` function.
I'm unable to catch when this is expiring or what to do next. 

I'm using Mobile SDK version 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in Mohith's answer the refresh token may have an indefinite lifetime. The issue here is not regarding the validity period but in the SDK it's calling an incorrect failure function at line 336 of cordova.force.js. `error` should be replaced by `fail`. This has been fixed in v2.2

Answer (score 5):

> The refresh token may have an indefinite lifetime, persisting for an admin-configured interval or until explicitly revoked by the end-user.

Since refresh tokens may expire or be revoked by the user outside the control of the client application, the client must handle failure to obtain an access token, typically by replaying the protocol from the start.

In your connected app settings in salesforce you will find refresh token policy .Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mohith, I have chosen **Refresh token is valid until revoked** option as the Refresh Token Policy as in above which am thinking it should valid until I explicitly revoke that. But still without a clue for me it's failing

Comment: @highfive I have observed this and it happens when salesforce servers due to some reason stop for small fraction of seconds.In UI during this time we get salesforce Internal Server error .You can visit trust.salesforce.com to figure the health of your server Instance .Also change your org to some other instance and replicate issue if it persists .Best wishes